# Does WCF play well with Java?

Tags: c#, java, wcf

Which of the WCF Service Protocols work well with Java?

Do the TCP Service Bindings work with java remoting (either Corba, EJB, JMS, etc.)?

What about the WebServices exposed as Service EndPoints.  Have these been tested against the common Java WebServices stack for interoperability?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use one of the HTTP bindings.   The TCP binding requires WCF to be on both sides.

Comment: Spec for the TCP protocol: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff470920(v=PROT.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have had some bad experiences when dealing with a Java based web service using the WS-Security specs. In that case there was very little, and mostly conflicting, documentation and no tech support at all from the vendor. It took us quite a bit of time to get it working but using a WS-Security sample as the basis we got everything working in the end.

The main problem was working against a poorly document black box system with security enabled makes it hard to figure out where you are going wrong, with or without WCF.

Answer (score 1):

WCF has been tested with Sun's Java WEbservices stack and Apache's Axis for interoperability.

So, I'd say it's pretty good.

Can you elaborate on "OR DOES TCP WORK AS WELL" ?

thank you,

Comment: not really any need to elaborate, MS is very clear that anything TCP in WCF is purely proprietary, even to the point that they discourage anybody attempting to port the serializer to other languages